# Input specific model numbers in textbox, and nothing else

Tags: html, text, input, textbox, numbers

What I want to do is make it so that when a user inputs these values **PIV13RT, PIV13RT2, PIV13RT3** into a text box, it will recognized. The problem is that you're able too input **PIV13RT1**, because the one is already present - which I don't want to be the case. Is there anyway to stop this? Thanks. Take a look at my code.

Basically, It's been tested and everything else seems to work. It's just it sees **PIV13RT1** as a value when it souldn't be.

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="modlenumber" pattern="^[PIV13RT2-3]+{7,8}$" title="Your 
Model Number." placeholder="Please Input a Modle number" size="35"
maxlength="8"><input name="" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: If you wish to allow three alternatives only, why not use a set of radio buttons or a `select` element? That would be more convenient to the user, as the values are relatively complicated to type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this pattern work for you?

```
^DIV13RT[23]?$
```

You wrapped the text you're searching for (DIV13RT) with a square brackets. They're used to match **any** of the containing characters so it matched every value which has at least "D" or "I" or "V" or "R" or "T" and so on.

Comment: Worked briliantly! Thank you!!